# I am trying to write a RTMP publisher application in C++ using RTMP lib

Tags: c++, rtmp, flash-media-server

I am trying to write a RTMP publisher application in C++ using RTMP lib . I am successful in making a net connection , now I want to publish a video [flv format] on the server. Could any one suggest the correct usage of the RTMP lib and the classes in it  in this regard . Any help in this regard would be very help ful.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: That's a pretty broad question...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Publishing a stream using librtmp in C/C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524587/publishing-a-stream-using-librtmp-in-c-c)