# librtmp example c programming?

Tags: c, rtmp, flv, wowza

Hi guys im new to c programming and would like to know if anyone has a really simple example to open a .flv file and send to a wowza server using librtmp.

Ive found a lot of code that is able to connect using the library but not a lot on publishing an flv.

Basically:

init librtmp -> enable write -> connect -> packetize flv -> send packets until finish

EDIT:

Okay so i have to open my flv file first and isolate each packet in the flv file to send it to librtmp. So far ive found this code:

https://github.com/noirotm/flvmeta/blob/master/src/flv.c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the author of FLVMeta here.

You might want to have a look at my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524587/publishing-a-stream-using-librtmp-in-c-c): https://stackoverflow.com/a/13803143/393701

In addition to this information, I can explain some parts of a C++ software that I wrote (unfortunately not open-source for the moment) which purpose it to stream FLV files to an RTMP server.

This has been tested and works fine with Wowza, nginx-rtmp, as well as the Dailymotion live streaming server.

#### Initializing

```
std::string rtmp_url = "rtmp://server/app/stream";
// add this if doing live streaming:
rtmp_url.append(" live=1");

RTMP * rtmp = RTMP_Alloc();
if (!rtmp) {
    std::cerr << "Unable to create rtmp object\n";
    return;
}

RTMP_Init(rtmp);
RTMP_LogSetLevel(RTMP_LOGINFO);
RTMP_LogSetOutput(stderr);
RTMP_SetupURL(rtmp, const_cast<char*>(rtmp_url.c_str())); // librtmp is a mess
RTMP_EnableWrite(rtmp);
```

The weird `const_cast` is due to the fact that the librtmp has been oddly designed, and uses a non-const `char *` as URL, even though it might not be modified actually by the library.
Also, the buffer will be used for as long as the RTMP object lives, so the string must not be freed before deleting the RTMP object.

#### Connecting

```
// connect to server
if (!RTMP_Connect(rtmp, NULL)) {
    std::cerr << "Unable to connect to server\n";
    RTMP_Free(rtmp);
    return;
}
```

The second argument to `RTMP_Connect` is an optional pointer to RTMP packet to send as a parameter to the connection instead of the default connection packet sent by librtmp. This normally should not be used when connecting to 'normal' RTMP servers.

```
// connect to stream (this will be the stream specified in the RTMP URL)
if (!RTMP_ConnectStream(rtmp, 0)) {
    cerr << "Unable to connect to stream\n";
    RTMP_Free(rtmp);
    return;
}
```

The second argument to `RTMP_ConnectStream` is an integer representing the timestamp to seek to when playing a video. When publishing, using `0` is a safe bet.

#### Publishing packets

This section assumes the use of the FLV code found in the FLVMeta project (see https://github.com/noirotm/flvmeta/blob/master/src/flv.h#L175).

```
flv_stream * flvin = flv_open(input_file.c_str());
if (!flvin) {
    std::cerr << "Unable to open " << input_file << '\n';
    return;
}
```

First, it is a good idea to make sure we have opened a real FLV file.

```
flv_header header;
int res = flv_read_header(flvin, &header);
if (res == FLV_ERROR_NO_FLV || res == FLV_ERROR_EOF) {
    std::cerr << "Input file is not an FLV video\n";
    flv_close(flvin);
    return;
}
```

Now read every tag in the file, and send them to the RTMP server.

```
// 10 MB copy buffer should be enough
#define BUFFER_SIZE 10000000
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

flv_tag tag;
while (flv_read_tag(flvin, &tag) != FLV_ERROR_EOF) {
    // copy tag header
    flv_copy_tag(buffer, &tag, FLVSTREAMER_BUFFER_SIZE);

    // copy tag body
    size_t data_size = flv_read_tag_body(flvin, buffer + FLV_TAG_SIZE, BUFFER_SIZE - FLV_TAG_SIZE);

    // copy previous tag size
    uint32 pts;
    flv_read_prev_tag_size(flvin, &pts);
    flv_copy_prev_tag_size(
        buffer + FLV_TAG_SIZE + flv_tag_get_body_length(tag),
        pts,
        BUFFER_SIZE - (FLV_TAG_SIZE + flv_tag_get_body_length(tag))
    );

    // write the packet
    int size = FLV_TAG_SIZE + data_size + sizeof(uint32);
    if (RTMP_Write(rtmp, buffer, size) <= 0) {
        std::cerr << "Unable to write to server" << endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

The various `flv_*` functions take care of handling the specificities of the FLV format, for example endianness issues, and the eventual malforming of data, so I would recommend using them if your program is compatible with the GPL license.
If not, it is not complicated to use standard I/O to iterate through tags, as long as the FLV format is well understood.

It is also important to note that the FLV file header must not be sent. librtmp will detect any attempt to send the FLV header and prevent it.

It is not mandatory to read incoming RTMP packets while publishing, but if you want to properly handle the protocol, the approach used by @szatmary in his code is recommended.

Another important aspect that is not handled here is that when publishing a live stream, it is mandatory to implement some form of throttling in order to send data at the nominal bitrate of the video, otherwise the RTMP server will skip packets and video playback will suffer greatly.
A common approach to solve this problem could be to read each tag's timestamp, and sleep if we are writing too fast.

#### Cleaning up

```
flv_close(flvin);
RTMP_Free(rtmp);
```

The `RTMP_Free` function will take care of closing the stream, the connection, and free any allocated memory.

Comment: Thank you very much, i was looking for c code, but the explanation works now has me on the right track :)

Comment: @SirDarius I am looking for RTMP Server example, how that work with your above cpp client code?

Comment: @AJit This does not seem to be in the scope of this question. Do you want to write an RTMP server from scratch? librtmp is only a client-side library.

Comment: Yes @SirDarius, I ended up connecting and streaming through FFMPEG.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple example I wrote in C++ https://github.com/szatmary/RtmpBroadcaster/blob/master/rtmp.cpp

Comment: how would you open the flv file and use this function? sendTag(FlvTag &tag)

Comment: Look at the rest of the RtmpBroadcaster project on git hub. It is a complete solution.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, could you please point me in the right direction, looking at your code, i guess i have to get familiar with flv first and how to read the data structure in order to use it with librtmp. Am i right? do you have any url or somewhere to start?

Comment: http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/flv/pdfs/video_file_format_spec_v10.pdf